# PHP Search in Array

Tags: php, arrays, search

We have an array, for example:

```
$my_array = array('Software Engineering', 'Civil Engineering', 'Hardware Engineering', 'BL AH Engineering');
```

Now I have a "$q" variable, I want to search between values of the array, remove the keys which doesn't contain $q, here is my code:

```
foreach($my_array as $key => &$value){
    if (stripos(($value), $q) === false){
        unset($my_array[$key]);
    }
}
```

now if we set the $q = 'eer':

```
var_dump($my_array);
array
  0 => string 'Software Engineering' (length=20)
  1 => string 'Civil Engineering' (length=17)
  2 => string 'Hardware Engineering' (length=20)
  3 => &string 'BL AH Engineering' (length=17)
```

as you see, nothing is removed since all the $values have 'eer' in 'Engineering'
it's OK, but now I set `$q = 'eer civil'`, now:

```
var_dump($my_array);
array
  empty
```

all the items are removed, but actually the 'Civil Engineering' contains both the 'eer' and 'civil', so it should not be removed, how I could make this work? I may explode the $q with ' space ' but it's not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us you code that uses `explode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `explode` should work:

***Update***

Use `preg_split` and `trim` to get rid of multiple/leading/trailing delimiters.

```
$array = array('Software Engineering', 'Civil Engineering', 'Hardware Engineering', 'BL AH Engineering');
$query = ' eer   civil ';
$query = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($query));
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($query as $q) {
        if (stripos($value, $q) === false) {
            unset($array[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($array);
```

http://codepad.org/r3jJX1aP

Comment: set q = 'eer ', attention to the space after 'eer', 'eer ' should return all of them and not empty

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is the right answer, but today I found a class which allows you to search in arrays with wildcards.

Source: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7696-PHP-Search-for-patterns-in-arrays-using-wildcards.html

Example:

"5. search array from array keys and values with a word "one" which can be anywhere in a keys or values"

```
$result = $array_search -> array_like($array, '%one%', 'both', false );
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode` should solve your problem

```
<?php 

$my_array = array('Software Engineering', 'Civil Engineering', 'Hardware Engineering', 'BL AH Engineering');

$str = "eer Software";
$str = explode(' ', $str);

foreach ($my_array as $key => $result) {
    foreach($str as $q){
        if (stripos(($result), $q) === false){
            unset($my_array[$key]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($my_array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for multiple values, pass them in an array, so `$q` will be an array of strings, instead of just one string, like so:

```
$q = array('eer'); // USE THIS FOR ONE parameter
//$q = array('Civil,'eer'); //USE THIS for several
foreach($my_array as $key => &$value){
    foreach($q as $qval) {
       if (stripos(($value), $qval) === false){
           unset($my_array[$key]);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: now set q = 'eer ' (attention to the space after eer, this is what ruining this, normally, 'eer ' should bring all the values but it reruns empty!)

Answer (score -1):

Try the array_search() function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

is a better way to search in a array.